# Best secure way for login by link in emai

Tags: php, security, email, web, authorization

Now I have a task to make login link in email. I watched how it's made by other websites and commonly they use hash for auto login to website.

In our website we have an order number and pin which we use to login for manage personal account.

My question is: Is there some secure reason for not using an order number and pin in link adders in email for login ?

Comment: - this information can be read by anyone with access to the email sent, so depending on how secure you need your system ...

Comment: I've never seen a site that auto logs you in from an email link.  Don't confuse email verification (i.e. verifying its a real email address) after signup with logging in. Automatically logging in via a link is never secure.

Comment: what's to stop someone from forwarding their email to everyone else? Now EVERYONE has access to that person's account because the login link was embedded within it.

Answer (score 0):

Generally spoken, having an auto-login in e-mail is rarely a good idea. Nevertheless, if you really need it, you should ensure that
a) the link can only be used once (a few times) AND
b) the link can only be used during a limited period of time

It doesn't matter if you use a hash or plain text regarding the auto-login functionality - if a man in the middle gets your mail, he can log in. What is it you want to hash? The order number and the pin? You will keep the hash server-side so that the pin and order-number are not directly visible in the mail? I would rather suggest to encrypt using a salt and append the salt to the encrypted link in the mail.

Comment: Am I clearly understand you? There is no reason from security point of view to use salt instead of order number and pin?

Comment: It depends on the sensitivity of the order number and the pin. I would not put any possibly sensitive information in a mail link and I don't understand why you want to have it in there. To put it in other words: You should follow a) and b) above and create a random URL which upon clicking on the server-side retrieves all the information that's needed to let the user continue his work (e.g. create a new session, retrieve an order number etc.)